# Remove parent product category slug from product_cat url woocommerce

Tags: permalinks, urls

Any way to remove parent product category slug from product category url ?

From `mywebsite.com/c/parent-cat/child-cat` to `mywebsite.com/c/child-cat`

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a solution using `woocommerce_taxonomy_args_product_cat` filter:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_taxonomy_args_product_cat', function( $tax_args ) { 
    $tax_args['rewrite']['hierarchical'] = false; 
    return $tax_args;
} );
```